# Exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c

i'm a beginner and my english is not well so sorry first. im trying to sum the numbers in a string (for a14fg5pk145 it returns 14+5+145), and it doesn't work:
"Exception thrown: read access violation.
str was 0x61."

this i my code:

```
void main()
{
    int x, i;
    char* pp;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    printf("Please enter numbers and letters:\n");
    gets(buffer);
    pp = buffer;
    x = SumStr(*pp);
    printf("%d", x);
}

int SumStr(char* str)
{
    int sum=0, num=0, flag = 0;
    while ((*str) != '\0')
    {
        while (((*str) > '1') && ((*str) < '9'))
        {
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                num += (*str);
                flag = 1;
            }
            else if (flag == 1)
                num = num * 10 + (*str);
            str++;
        }
        if (flag == 0)
            str++;
        sum += num;
        num = 0;
        flag = 0;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Another advise: `((*str) > '1') && ((*str) < '9')` is `isdigit(*str)`. Do not reinvent the wheel, use standard libraries.

Comment: Don't zeros count in your numbers?  Actually, you're excluding `0`, `1`, and `9`, which is bit unusual.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 2):

First problem with your code which is causing Exception.

```
x = SumStr(*pp);
```

it should be

```
x = SumStr(pp);
```

Because you should pass address of the string pointer not its first character by attaching asterix.

Second Issue that will not make it work is.

```
num += (*str);
```

and

```
num = num * 10 + (*str);
```

By (*str) you are actually adding the character ascii value instead of number.
This will solve the problem by changing the ascii value to number.

```
num += (*str) - '0';

num = num * 10 + (*str) - '0';
```

Comment: 0 count on my numbers, i forgot it... thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This may serve your purpose

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, sum = 0, store;
    char str[] = "a14fg5pk145asdasdad6";
    int length = strlen(str);
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        store = 0;
        while(isdigit(str[i])) {
            store = (store * 10) + (str[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
        sum += store;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**output :**

```
170
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `pp`, not `*pp`, to the function `SumStr`. `*pp` has the type `char`, and the function expects `char *`. In fact, you do not even need `pp` at all, just pass the `buffer` as the parameter.

Also:

> [Never use gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the
>          data in advance how many  characters  gets()  will  read,  and  because
>          gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it
>          is extremely dangerous to use.  It has  been  used  to  break  computer
>          security.  Use fgets() instead.

Comment: The code should either declare `SumStr()` before it is used with a full prototype or moves its definition before `main()` so that the compiler can spot the misuse of the function.  As it stands, its hands are tied; it isn't allowed to report the trouble.